# Joining 2 lists Django

Tags: python, django

I have 2 ArrayField lists and I want to join them using the zip method so I can Iterate through two lists in Django my django templates. But the output is treating each as array as seperate lists.

my model

```
class programas(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=250)
    script = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=8000, blank=True))
    created_on = models.DateTimeField()
    show_date = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    script_eng = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=8000, blank=True))
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    description_eng = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    show_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

my view where I try to join the lists

```
def pages(request, id):

   obj = programas.objects.get(id=id)
   script = programas.objects.values_list('script')
   script_eng = programas.objects.values_list('script_eng')
   zip_scripts = list(zip(script , script_eng))


   context = {'title': obj.title,
              'show_date': obj.show_date,
              'script' : obj.script,
              'script_eng': obj.script_eng,
              'description': obj.description,
              'description_eng': obj.description_eng,
              'show_id':obj.show_id,
              'url': obj.url,
              'zip_scripts' : zip_scripts,
               }


   return render(request, 'rtves/pages.html', context)
```

my code on the template page

```
  {% if script %}             

            {% for text1, text2 in zip_scripts  %}                  
            <p> {{ text1  }} </p> 
            <p> {{ text2  }} </p>
            {% endfor %}

         {% else %} 
         <p>Nothing here</p>
         {% endif %}
```

Have I got to make changes in the database?

Comment: Can you show the current and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`programas.objects.values_list('script')` gives you a list of the script fields of *all* the programas objects in the database. So, you effectively have a list of lists.

What you probably want is just the fields from the object you already have. So there's no need to use `values_list` there.

```
obj = programas.objects.get(id=id)
script = obj.script
script_eng = obj.script_eng
```

or, just pass them straight to the zip (note, there's no need for `list` anyway):

```
obj = programas.objects.get(id=id)
zip_scripts = zip(obj.script, obj.script_eng)
```

Comment: Excellent thanks very much appreciated, the first option worked straight away. Thanks Daniel.

Comment: The only reason you might want to use `list` is if you need to iterate over it in the template more than once I guess... (or have a reason to treat it as a sequence and not a one off iterable...)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it "doesn't" work on your perspective is that because when you cast querysets to built-in iterables, you don't get, an an iterable of the values but an iterable of one item tuples like

```
[('bill',), ('while',), ('participant',), ('you',)]
```

which, when you cast zip and list upon becomes even weirder, but you can simply flatter this with something like

```
list(map(o.itemgetter(0), qs))
```

In your case the whole code would be roughly

```
flatten = lambda qs: list(map(operator.itemgetter(0), qs))

script = flatten(programas.objects.values_list('script'))
script_eng = flatten(programas.objects.values_list('script_eng'))
# Then you can just zip them together and have what you wanted to begin with
zip_scripts = list(zip(script , script_eng))
```

Comment: Apparently I misunderstood and answered something entirely different, but you are welcome :D